# NSTableView selectable but not editable

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nstablecolumn

Trying to get an NSTableView in IB to be selectable but not editable.  But de-selecting "Editable" for a column also removes the selecting capability.

Can someone tell me where I should insert this code to make it work (not working in app delegate or window controller) :

```
NSTextFieldCell *aCell = [tableColumn dataCell];
[aCell setEditable: NO];
[aCell setSelectable: YES];
```

BTW that table is updated by dictionary bindings, and the dictionary controller is set to not editable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the columns to `Editable`, but the individual cell behaviour to `Selectable`.

Comment: this is the simplest way to do it.. and should be marked as an answer !

Answer (score 2):

I'd try implementing `tableView:shouldEditTableColumn:row:`in your NSTableViews delegate and return NO. See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDelegate/tableView%3ashouldEditTableColumn%3arow%3a).